# Throttling settings for Kendra Index WebCrawlers on Atlassian pages

Tags: web-crawler, confluence, throttling, amazon-kendra

Is there a known throttling max that keeps AWS Kendra WebCrawler from getting blocked when running on an Atlassian Confluence page?

I'm running the crawler on a technical specification on a master document that has children pages organized into hierarchies. Then I get this error I found from CloudWatch:

sync failed due to telemetry errors:

but there is no detail of the telemetry error.
I know this means its a AWS DataSync transfer error.
How can I get more detail on the telemetry error?